# Какой знак следует поставить?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

*Дурак (?) больше нечего сказать.*

На мой взгляд, здесь уместно тире, но я никак не могу понять, по какому правилу оно может ставиться. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире допускается, но лучше поставить запятую:

***Дурак**, больше нечего сказать.*

1. Это **бессоюзное** сложное предложение (БСП). В первой части **номинатив**, выраженный сущ. в И.п. Если точнее — постпозитивный **оценочный** номинатив по отношению к предыдущему контексту.

Во второй части **безлично-инфинитивное** предложение (инфинитив + отрицательное местоимение).

2. Отношения между частями предложения **присоединительные**: оценка + комментарий к предыдущей оценке. **Основное** содержание в первой части, поэтому лучше поставить **запятую**. При постановке **тире** вторая часть будет более значимой, чем нужно
3. И по **интонации** здесь логически подчеркнута первая часть, а пауза перед "комментарием" небольшая. Если посмотреть примеры в Сети, то там ставят запятую (запись **по слуху**): ***Дурак**, больше нечего сказать. **Ну дурак дураком**, больше нечего сказать!*